# Open Activity from url is not working android

Tags: android, deep-linking

Hello friends i want to open my application when particular type of url is being called in browser (Predefined format)

following is rout on server

```
Redirect::to('intent://com.customlymade.activit/#Intent;scheme=customlymade;package=com.customlymade.activity;end');
```

and following is the intent filter i am using in my manifest file

```
<intent-filter>
    <data
        android:host="com.customlymade.activity"
        android:scheme="customlymade" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

But Nothing is working Please help.

Comment: Could you maybe add `<application>` and `<activity>` definition too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, that the redirect is executed automatically. Chrome in android has a security feature, that starting an activity can only be done after a user action (like clicking on a link). See chapter "See also" at https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents

> And Chrome doesn’t launch an external app for a given Intent URI in the following cases.
>
> - When the Intent URI is redirected from a typed in URL.
> - When the Intent URI is initiated without user gesture.

Comment: But i have tried some apps which are having same functionality Like The Hunt Application (And that is the sad part of my life)

Comment: I can only imagine, that they do some trick, to let chrome believe, it was a user gesture. In the standard it is not possible. You can look at the source code of the website of the hunt application to get an idea what they are doing. But it is not recommended! At some day, google will fix that issue and your trick will stop working. So, don't do it.